# Check whether a string list contains other string list items using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two dynamic lists. I want to verify one list contains the strings of other list.

for Ex:

```
        list1 = 'test1, test2, test3, test4, test5'
        list2 = 'how, where, why, test2, test1'
```

I want to validate the second list, whether every string of list2 is in list1 or not? I want to use it in the stored procedure in SQL server.

Could you please provide the solution?

Comment: If you tried any code, could you add with question?

Comment: When you say list you mean do you have the `column` with multiple rows or declared variable with list values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try the below method also

```
   declare @l1 varchar(max),@l2 varchar(max),@result varchar(max)
set @l1 = 'test1, test2, test3, test4, test5' 
set @l2 = 'how, where, why, test2, test1'

select  'l1' as id,ltrim(t.c.value('.','varchar(max)')) as n  into #t1 from 
(select  x= cast('<t>'+replace(@l1,',','</t><t>')+'</t>' as xml)) a cross apply x.nodes('/t') t(c)

select  'l2' as id,ltrim(t.c.value('.','varchar(max)')) as n  into #t2 from 
(select  x= cast('<t>'+replace(@l2,',','</t><t>')+'</t>' as xml)) a cross apply x.nodes('/t') t(c)

select @result= (select n+',' from #t1 where n in(select n from #t2) for xml path(''))

drop table #t1, #t2
select @result
```